# Accessing Python class @property in generator

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my CurrencyLot class:

```
class CurrencyLot(models.Model):
    _amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_expired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    _usage_count = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['expiry_date',]

    @property
    def amount(self):
        if self._usage_count < 1 or self.is_expired:
            return 0
        else:
            return self._amount

    @property
    def usage_count(self):
        return self._usage_count

    def set_amount(self, amount):
        self._amount = amount
        self.save()
        return self._amount
```

I have amount as 'private' variable, and use @property to access it.
This function is throwing error:

```
def deduct_amount(self, deduction):
        deduction = int(deduction)
        currency_lots_iterator = self.currency_lots.filter(is_expired=False).iterator()
        while deduction > 0:
            if deduction > currency_lots_iterator.amount:
                deduction -= currency_lots_iterator.amount
                currency_lots_iterator.set_amount(0)
                currency_lots_iterator.next()
            elif deduction == currency_lots_iterator.amount:
                deduction = 0
                currency_lots_iterator.set_amount(0)
            elif deduction < currency_lots_iterator.amount:
                deduction = 0
                currency_lots_iterator.set_amount(currency_lots_iterator.amount-deduction)
        return self.total_valid_amount()
```

The error is: AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'amount'.

Is there a method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `currency_lots_iterator` is a generator (iterating over objects from your QuerySet) - you have to fetch the next item from it and access amount from that:

```
currency_lots_iterator = self.currency_lots.filter(is_expired=False).iterator()
while deduction > 0:
    currency_lot = currency_lots_iterator.next()
```

Then use `currency_lot.amount` and `currency_lot.set_amount(x)`